# .Net Core app in docker container can't connect to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker

So I know there are a load of questions on SO related to this already, but I think at this point I've read them all, tried all the suggestions, and still haven't found a resolution.

I've got a simple .Net core MVC app with a connection to a local MSSQL database. I have been unable to get it to connect to SQL when running it in a container... I just get an error that a connection couldn't be established. When run in IIS Express it connects fine.

My connection string is:

```
Data Source=10.11.56.36,1433;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=false;User id=testdb;Password=######;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

My container is launched via:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 testing
```

Here are the things I've attempted so far:

- Ensured the SQL server is configured to accept remote connections
- Used "host.docker.internal" for server name
- Ping'd the SQL server IP to ensure it's accessible to the container
- Verified port 1433 is allowed through the firewall
- Tried a different port and configured SQL server to listen on that
- Tried without the port in the connection string

There were a host of other things I've tried as well in the last few hours of beating my head on this, but I've made no progress at all. What am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked that your SQL Server instance is configured with `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode`?

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this bug is the reason for your error, if you are running a Linux Container:

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/29147

If so, the fix is to add the following to the runtime image in dockerfile

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-libs
ENV DOTNET_SYSTEM_GLOBALIZATION_INVARIANT=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. I spent 3 days and the fix for me was to use a fully qualified domain name.

MyServerName.MyDomain.com